# How to update C# version in Ranorex Studio?

Tags: automated-testing, c#, quality-assurance, ranorex

My project in Ranorex Studio (v8.3.1) is using .NET Framework 4.5.2 and C# 5.0. I want to leverage the features of newer C# versions e.g. [String Interpolation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated). So I want to upgrade my Ranorex Project to at least C# 6.0.

The problem is that when I go to Tools > Project Upgrade, I only see that .NET 4.6 and C# 5.0 are available in the dropdown for the upgrade.

What do I have to do get the latest/newer version of C# in Ranorex Studio so that I can upgrade my project within the Ranorex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ranorex isn't compatible with C# 6.0 or 7.0, [as noted in their forums](https://www.ranorex.com/forum/c-6-0-not-available-t11389.html).

One user mentioned that "there's nothing in C# 6/7 that you really have to have for writing Ranorex tests. There are lots of nice things, but they aren't necessary", and so OP had to re-write the code to be compatible with 5.0 or below.

Hope this helps - although I appreciate it's probably not what you wanted to hear.

Comment: Yes, I also saw that. I had an impression that their new release supports the newer versions of C#. Somehow another QA in the team has C# 6.0 in Ranorex but we could not figure out to update mine. I do agree that it is not necessary and can be worked around. Its just the fact that using different versions of C# in the same project by different team members create compilation errors for others.

Comment: No longer true. At least I am able to select C# 7.0 compiler version for my project in Project Settings / Compiling / Target Framework / Change.

Comment: @Sinatr yes, I was also able to update it. But I am not sure what results in the availability of newer versions of C# and .NET in Ranorex.